# Content-Disposition Attachment not working

Tags: content-disposition

I want to display a save as dialog like this when I click the button save
[image]

I am using content disposition but it is not working. Can someone please tell me why?

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit vague.

Let's start by the basic : is your header function called before any output ?

See http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp

Moreover you can't display that yourself.

You just can make the browser handle the download of your file.

It will ask you to choose if you want to "open with" or "save" file on the disk. If you choose the "save" option, then this window will open. You can't force the user to not have the choice "open as" as far as i know.

Comment: yes @Walfrat. What do I need to do?can you give me a sample on using this?

Comment: if you use native JAVASCRIPT. Use window.open in order to open a new tab/window which point at the URL to download your file (see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp). Or use a <a> tag with the href that point to the same url. Use target="blank" in order to make it open in another tab. see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: but this opens another window not the save as dialog that i need @Walfrat